# What does the "Differentiator" property mean in AWS route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

What does the  "Differentiator" property mean in AWS route53 DNS records properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about [routing policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html). For example, if you add an `IP-based` policy to a DNS record then it will act depending on the rule that you have. i.e. some web server traffic can be redirected to Asian servers based on client location. So, It differentiates the act while responding to the DNS query.